# How to make password visible in Ubuntu login screen?

Tags: password, login-screen

My six month-old child was hitting the keyboard of my locked laptop. And after some time I noticed that characters in the password entry field are visible (I mean not as asterisks).

Is this some kind of feature? And if so, how to reproduce this? Or is this some kind of security breach?

I am using Ubuntu 12.10 (quantal) 64-bit.

Comment: Seems like a bug.

Comment: Interesting. I am wondering what caused the visibility. Maybe the length of the string? Or maybe a combination of characters?

Comment: @don.joey It seems to be some kind of combination. I have just tried to enter a long string, but could not reproduce this visibility.

Comment: Don't you mean the 'lock' screen?

Comment: @wilf Yes, sorry, the lock screen.

Comment: Forgot to add smiley - :-). Can't find anything in `dconf`...

Comment: Phew!!! I was just about to ask this exact question. My 2 year old scribbled at my keyboard and viola! Happy to know its a feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also seemed to have this 'bug' and found out how to make the password visible.

**It is not a bug, but a feature**:

If you use **right-click** with your mouse the **context menu** opens. Then there is an option to toggle the password's visibility.

My keyboard has an option to open the context menu (just like the right click with the mouse), which is the key the kid must have hit accidentally to change the visibility

[image: Picture: Login Screen with opened context menu]

Comment: It is what is typed into the password field so not the password itself though ultimately those 2 need to be the same to log in. Seems pretty normal to me :) Good find so +1 :D

Comment: True, good find. In my case I don't have this menu key button on the keyboard, but I do have touchpad buttons in between the keyboard and the touchpad.